# Calling an Objective-C Method from a purely C++ class

Tags: c++, objective-c

I have a pure C++ class that needs to retrieve an `int` value from some Objective-C instance method.

I understand that C++ cannot call Objective-C methods directly.

I have an Objective-C++ class that allows me to work with Objective-C and also to pass data to my pure C++ class.

However, I have not figured out a way to allow the pure C++ class to request the `int` value be computed and retrieved. In other words, the pure C++ needs to be able to retrieve that value whenever it needs to (via a function pointer, or whatever).

Anyone know how this is accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ can definitely call Objective-C code. Store the code that communicates in a .mm file instead of .cpp, and Xcode will do the rest for you.

.mm files store Objective-C++ code, which is why it works.

**[Edit]**
You probably have some business logic in C++, and want to combine that with your UI in Objective-C, right? Your business logic is probably shared across multiple platforms, which is why you can't just compile all your code as Objective-C++.

That's why you can basically "wrap" your Objective-C code in an Objective-C++ wrapper.

```
// myUI.h (C++ header)
class myUI {
    void doSomething1();
    int doSomething2();
}

// main.cpp (C++ code)
int main() {
    myUI ui;
    printf("%d\n", ui.doSomething2());
    ui.doSomething1();
    return 0;
}

// myUI.mm (Objective-C++ code)
int myUI::doSomething2() {
    return [[MyController sharedController] doSomething2];
}

// myUI.cpp (C++ code)
void myUI::doSomething1() {
    printf("Hi!\n");
}
```

Comment: I know that works, but I don't want to take that approach. I want my pure C++ classes to remain pure C++. I don't want to compile all my C++ code as Objective-C++ code.

Comment: So make sure to only compile the communicating code as Objective-C++ code. You can just prototype that one method in a normal .h file, and put the code in the .mm file, separated from the rest of the code. You don't immediately have to compile *all* your code as Objective-C++, only the part that uses Objective-C++ code.

Comment: You'll have to explain in a bit more detail, preferably with a code sample, because I don't follow.

Comment: ty, that looks like it should do it :)